# asp.net mvc 3 razor login view does not returning requested url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

After logging in, the user does not get returned to the requested URL.

This is the **controller**:

```
 public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UserIsValid(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                if (model.RememberMe == false)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        model.Username,
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                        false,
                        "user",
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                    string HashedCoockies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, HashedCoockies);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**view:**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
                <label for="username">
                    Username:</label>
                <br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username)
                <br />
                <br />
                <label for="password">
                    Password:</label>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
                <br />
                <br />
                <div id="lower">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe, new { style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 7px; position: absolute;" })
                    <label for="check" id="keep" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: -14px;">
                        Keep me logged in</label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="round-button" style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;" />
                </div>
}
```

and **web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

p.s. my login.cshtml does not have _Layout.html

Comment: What does "login view does not returning on requested url" mean? Do you stay on the login page? What is the url in the browser after login?
Have you put a breakpoint on the line `return Redirect(returnUrl);`? Is it being hit and the `returnUrl` is containing the right value?

Comment: Now returnUrl is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returnUrl can be null. returnUrl will have a value when the url is in this format

http://localhost:56457/Account/LogIn?returnUrl=whatever_return_url

when you try to access whatever_return_url (which requires authorization prior to the access) it would redirect you to the login page with the returnUrl added (meaning you haven't logged in prior)

which means if your login is successful it should take you whatever_return_url. If returnUrl is not specified (ie: if returnUrl is null) it should take you to 'Index' action of the 'Home' controller after login.

http://localhost:56457/Home/Index

Check thoroughly your controller, action names and the validity of the URLs